# python selenium joining items in a list

Tags: python, selenium, automation

ok I want to automatically sign up for google but the problem is it joining two items in a list in the email it should only take the assigned to it the fourth item
here is the code and the list that was used also I tried `time.sleep` also tried debugging

```
#login data
loginG=[]
length=9
for i in range (4):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase  
    data=''.join((random.sample(letters, length)))
    loginG.append(data) 

loginG.pop(3)

lth=4

for i in range (1):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase  
    data=''.join((random.sample(letters,lth )))
    loginG.append(data) 

#Functions
def google():
    file = open("F:\Python\Python programs\Project\Bots\data.txt", "w") 
    file.write("loginG:"+str(loginG)+" time:"+str(now))
    file.close()
    fistnameG=(loginG[0])
    lastnameG=(loginG[1])
    emailG=('burner'+loginG[3]+'@gmail.com')
    passwordG=(loginG[2])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="F:\Python\Python programs\Project\Bots\driver\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?hl=en&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp')
    FirstnameG = driver.find_element_by_id('firstName')
    FirstnameG.send_keys(fistnameG)
    LastnameG=driver.find_element_by_id('lastName')
    LastnameG.send_keys(lastnameG)
    EmailG=driver.find_element_by_name('Username')
    time.sleep(3)
    EmailG.send_keys(emailG)
    time.sleep(2)
    PasswordG = driver.find_element_by_name('Passwd')
    PasswordG.send_keys(passwordG)
    confirmpasswordG=driver.find_element_by_name('ConfirmPasswd')
    confirmpasswordG.send_keys(passwordG)
    nextG=driver.find_element_by_class_name('VfPpkd-vQzf8d')
    time.sleep(2)
    nextG.click()
```

also I am using selenium to interact with the website random and  string to generate random letters, the list that was used was `loginG:['racthjdgb', 'jqzgwkcom', 'dxrochpzm', 'wvbo']`

here is the output: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/928576191307325440/928613805284524072/unknown.png?width=769&height=614

my desired output is `burnerwvbo@gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
 EmailG=driver.find_element_by_name('Username')
 time.sleep(3)
 EmailG.clear()
 EmailG.send_keys(emailG)
```

First, it inputs the previous text form list, but then clears off and inputs the 3rd item

[image: UI Snapshot]